# Can I give replicate permissions to workflow-service user in AEM

Tags: aem

I have created a launcher to trigger Activation workflow (which will check whether user has replicate permissions or not), when the asset is modified.
When the asset is modified, workflow is triggered, the Initiator is showing as "workflow-service" user instead of the original user who updated the asset. And workflow instance is stopped as workflow-service don't have replicate permissions.

1. Is it a good idea to provide replicate permissions to workflow-service?
2. Can I trigger a workflow using a system user via launcher?

Expectation: Workflow should run without stopping in review step

Comment: If it is always the workflow-service user, why you need to check for permissions if you will replicate the asset anyways?